# How to get the record from the date today onward?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have a table having the following fields. `event_id`, `month`, `day`, `year`, `event`, `place`. What I want is to display the upcoming record based on the date. Here is my code which give me all the data.

```
$news = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM tblupcomingevents limit 5") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($news))                  
<?php echo $row ["month"] ?>
<?php echo $row ["day"] ?>
<?php echo $row ["year"] ?>
<?php echo $row ["event"] ?>
<?php echo $row ["place"] ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you should store the date in one column an then use them on the fly using date function according to your need
In that case you can use the below query

```
$news = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM tblupcomingevents WHERE date >= DATE(NOW()) limit 5") or die(mysql_error());
```

You can achieve the same in the current situation also but you will have to get result from database then you will loop it and check for the future once and will store them in an final array and then again will use the array further.

So it will take load and not an optimized approach

Comment: Its not working. My date is like this December, 23, 2014.. I have already put it on one column

Comment: @DaniloEscapa You will have to store it in the mysql format yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 2):

Best Solution is to store your dates in database in `date()` format
then use following query

```
 SELECT *  FROM tblupcomingevents WHERE event_date >= CURRENT_DATE() order by event__date limit 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper solution would probably be to change your database to actually save the event's **date** and then just query on it:

```
SELECT * FROM tblupcomingevents WHERE event_date >= CURRENT_DATE() LIMIT 5
```

If this is not possible, you can construct a similar behavior with the [`str_to_date`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   tblupcomingevents 
WHERE  STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`year`, `month`, `day`), '%Y%m%d') >=
       CURRENT_DATE()
LIMIT  5
```

Answer (score 1):

Best Solution is to store your dates in database in `date()` format
then use following query

```
SELECT *  FROM tblupcomingevents WHERE event_date >= CURRENT_DATE() order by event__date limit 5;


$news = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM tblupcomingevents WHERE event_date >= CURRENT_DATE() order by event__date limit 5") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($news))                  
<?php echo $row ["event_date"] ?>
<?php echo $row ["event"] ?>
<?php echo $row ["place"] ?>
```